# What's the best method to identify outliers and influential cases for linear mixed models?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, outliers

I've seen many many many different questions on how to *extract* Leverage and Cook's distance for Lmers. I'm able to do that with different packages and functions by now, but how should I **interpret** them ? I've seen many different answers to that ...

A more general question should be: **What's the best method to identify outliers and influential cases for linear mixed models?**. For now, I believe Leverage and Cook's distance would do the job, but I'm open to better methods.

- A reproducible example:

```r
### fit model:
ModAdditive <- lmer(SCORE ~ PROFICIENCY_c + TASK_TYPE + (1|ID), 
     data = data, REML = FALSE)
```

- extracting Leverage and Cook's values:

```r
### Check for outliers and influential cases:

### Check for general outliers:

data %>% dplyr::select(ID, SCORE, PROFICIENCY_c, TASK_TYPE) %>% 
  group_by(TASK_TYPE) %>% rstatix::identify_outliers(SCORE) 

### leverage: ### 

library(HLMdiag) ## or
library(influence.ME) ## or

# with: library(HLMdiag):

influential <- HLMdiag::hlm_influence(ModAdditive, value = fixef)

### with lme4:
hatvalues(ModAdditive)

### with influence.ME: 

influence(ModAdditive, obs = TRUE)

### Cook's distance ###

### Calculate Cook's distance: 

cooksd <- cooks.distance(ModAdditive) ## with stats

HLMdiag::hlm_influence(modAdditive) ## with hlm
```

- Questions:
- **Question1**: is this the best approach to account for outliers in the data?
- **Question2**: For Cook's distance, I've seen that no obs should have and absolute value greater than 1, so would this be correct:

```r
### check if there is any value bigger than 1: 
### ref: no greater than 1 (FIELD, 2012) or 4/n (the whole internet)

if (any(abs(cooksd) > 1)) {
  print('yey')
} else {
  print('no') 
}
```

- **Question 3** : for Leverage values, I've seen: *# Leverage values can lie between 0 (indicating that the case has no influence whatsoever) # and 1 (indicating that the case has complete influence over prediction). If no cases exert undue influence over the model then we would expect all of the leverage values to be close to the average value ((k + 1)/n). (FIELD, 2012)*

So, should I check if any values in `influential$leverage.overall` is > 1 ? Would that be enough? How should I interpret `influential$mdffits` `influential$covtrace` `influential$covratio` ?

- **Question4** : how good is `performance` [check_outilers() function?](https://rdrr.io/cran/performance/man/check_outliers.html)
- data:

```r
dput(data)
structure(list(ID = structure(c("PART_1", "PART_1", "PART_2", 
"PART_2", "PART_3", "PART_3", "PART_4", "PART_4", "PART_5", "PART_5", 
"PART_6", "PART_6", "PART_7", "PART_7", "PART_8", "PART_8", "PART_9", 
"PART_9", "PART_10", "PART_10", "PART_11", "PART_11", "PART_12", 
"PART_12", "PART_13", "PART_13", "PART_14", "PART_14", "PART_15", 
"PART_15", "PART_16", "PART_16", "PART_17", "PART_17", "PART_18", 
"PART_18", "PART_19", "PART_19", "PART_20", "PART_20", "PART_21", 
"PART_21", "PART_22", "PART_22", "PART_23", "PART_23", "PART_24", 
"PART_24", "PART_25", "PART_25", "PART_26", "PART_26", "PART_27", 
"PART_27", "PART_28", "PART_28", "PART_29", "PART_29", "PART_30", 
"PART_30", "PART_31", "PART_31", "PART_32", "PART_32", "PART_33", 
"PART_33", "PART_34", "PART_34", "PART_35", "PART_35", "PART_36", 
"PART_36", "PART_37", "PART_37", "PART_38", "PART_38", "PART_39", 
"PART_39", "PART_40", "PART_40", "PART_41", "PART_41", "PART_42", 
"PART_42", "PART_43", "PART_43", "PART_44", "PART_44", "PART_45", 
"PART_45", "PART_46", "PART_46", "PART_47", "PART_47", "PART_48", 
"PART_48", "PART_49", "PART_49", "PART_50", "PART_50", "PART_51", 
"PART_51", "PART_52", "PART_52", "PART_53", "PART_53", "PART_54", 
"PART_54", "PART_55", "PART_55", "PART_56", "PART_56", "PART_57", 
"PART_57", "PART_58", "PART_58", "PART_59", "PART_59", "PART_60", 
"PART_60", "PART_61", "PART_61", "PART_62", "PART_62", "PART_63", 
"PART_63", "PART_64", "PART_64", "PART_65", "PART_65", "PART_66", 
"PART_66", "PART_67", "PART_67", "PART_68", "PART_68", "PART_69", 
"PART_69", "PART_70", "PART_70", "PART_71", "PART_71"), class = c("glue", 
"character")), SCORE = c(65.7, 65.08, 65.8, 61, 74.45, NA, 68, 
71.18, NA, 68.46, NA, NA, 53.75, 62.75, 73.94, 66.32, 67.24, 
73.42, 58.22, 59.83, NA, NA, NaN, 51.8, 71.07, 64.77, 68.07, 
67.88, NaN, NaN, 69.88, 72.27, 71.32, 64.25, 62.18, NaN, 58.65, 
62.6, 76.45, 54.75, 71.13, 64.74, 67.25, NA, NaN, NaN, 51.76, 
51.58, 69.33, 67.05, 68.17, 62.38, 58, 64.57, 54.27, NA, 68.05, 
65.56, NaN, NaN, NA, NA, 61, 70.71, 61.67, NA, NA, NA, 67.79, 
68.1, 65.93, NA, NA, 58.43, NA, NA, 59.27, 55, 69.67, 65.29, 
71.38, NA, 70, 58.86, NaN, NaN, 64.88, 64.18, 68.19, NA, 62.06, 
70.33, 61, 58.5, 55.48, 64.84, 65.67, 65.19, 67.72, 63.14, 68.47, 
59.12, 64, NaN, 65.11, 62.75, 66, NA, 67.5, NaN, 66.33, 68.82, 
NA, 65.04, 69.61, 66.78, 69.33, 64.86, 75.67, 69.06, 68.17, 69.94, 
63, 59.31, NA, 65.15, 58.81, 55.83, NA, 67.71, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
66.5, 69, 62.33, 58.83, 65, 60.65, NA, NA), PROFICIENCY_c = c(41.32, 
41.32, -22.68, -22.68, -26.68, -26.68, 37.32, 37.32, -47.68, 
-47.68, -46.68, -46.68, -26.68, -26.68, 13.32, 13.32, 41.32, 
41.32, 5.32, 5.32, -56.68, -56.68, -39.68, -39.68, 40.32, 40.32, 
27.32, 27.32, 1.32, 1.32, 49.32, 49.32, 36.32, 36.32, -23.68, 
-23.68, 1.32, 1.32, -49.68, -49.68, 19.32, 19.32, 2.32, 2.32, 
2.32, 2.32, 8.32, 8.32, 46.32, 46.32, 40.32, 40.32, -7.68, -7.68, 
-37.68, -37.68, 6.32, 6.32, -28.68, -28.68, -57.78, -57.78, 18.32, 
18.32, -4.68, -4.68, -44.68, -44.68, 44.32, 44.32, -10.68, -10.68, 
-57.98, -57.98, -56.68, -56.68, -19.68, -19.68, 35.32, 35.32, 
21.32, 21.32, -50.68, -50.68, -28.68, -28.68, 44.32, 44.32, 54.32, 
54.32, 32.32, 32.32, 0.32, 0.32, -2.68, -2.68, 27.32, 27.32, 
40.32, 40.32, 13.32, 13.32, -24.68, -24.68, -26.68, -26.68, -52.68, 
-52.68, -14.68, -14.68, 40.32, 40.32, 6.32, 6.32, 39.32, 39.32, 
51.32, 51.32, 43.32, 43.32, 28.32, 28.32, -8.68, -8.68, 30.32, 
30.32, -22.68, -22.68, 34.32, 34.32, -50.68, -50.68, -47.68, 
-47.68, 19.32, 19.32, -10.68, -10.68, 18.32, 18.32, -54.68, -54.68
), TASK_TYPE = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "A"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-142L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Since doing anything about these findings can distort inference, you have to question why do them.  (That is especially true for outliers).  Best to use methods that are not greatly effected by outliers or high leverage points.  For outliers, semiparametric ordinal models can be used (see [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo)) and for collinearities, reformulate the model using unsupervised learning (data reduction) techniques such as variable clustering.  I go into this in [Chapter 4 of RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc).